# Как избавится от <ng-component> который автоматически подставляется если нет selector у компонента

Tags: angular

В файле app.component.html есть

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Роутинг:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent }
];
```

Когда я на сайте захожу по пути /user/
Я хочу чтобы внутрь router-outlet тэга подставлялся html код моего компонента, но если добавить selector у компонента

```
@Component({
  selector: '[user]', // or just 'user'
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
})
```

То я вижу тэг div, а если удалить селектор

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
})
```

То я вижу тэг ng-component

Можно ли как то избавится от этих тэгов?

Comment: А по-моему никак...